# Fastest way to extract a column and then find its uniq items in a large delimited file

Tags: shell, sorting, awk

Hoping for help.  I have a 3 million line file, data.txt, delimited with "|", e.g,.

```
"4"|"GESELLSCHAFT FUER NUCLEONIC & ELECT MBH"|"DE"|"0"
"5"|"IMPEX ESSEN VERTRIEB VON WERKZEUGEN GMBH"|"DE"|"0"
```

I need to extract the 3rd column ("DE") and then limit it to its unique values.  Here is what I've come up with (gawk and gsort as I'm running MacOS and only had the "--parallel" option via GNU sort):

```
gawk -F "|" '{print $3}' data.txt \
    | gsort --parallel=4  -u > countries.uniq
```

This works, but it isn't very fast.  I have similar tasks coming up with some even larger (11M record) files, so I'm wondering if anyone can point out a faster way.

I hope to stay in shell, rather than say, Python, because some of the related processing is much easier done in shell.

Many thanks!

Comment: Why not using `uniq`?

Comment: I think there is no much overhead in your code due to the shell, and unix tools like `gawk`and `gsort` are highly optimized.

Comment: Can you comment if the below solution was faster for your input ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` is tailor-made for such tasks. Here is a minimal `awk` logic that could do the trick for you.

```
awk -F"|" '!($3 in arr){print} {arr[$3]++} END{ for (i in arr) print i}' logFile
```

The logic is as `awk` processes every line, it adds the entry of the value in `$3` only if it has not seen it before. The above prints both unique lines followed by unique entries from `$3`

If you want the unique lines only, you can exclude the `END()` clause

```
awk -F"|" '!($3 in arr){print} {arr[$3]++}' logFile > uniqueLinesOnly
```

If you want unique values only from the file remove the inside `print`

```
awk -F"|" '!($3 in arr){arr[$3]++} END{ for (i in arr) print i}' logFile > uniqueEntriesOnly
```

You can see how fast it is for a 11M record entry file. You can write it a new file using the redirect operator

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. Your solution is quick to produce only one line per value of field 3, which is great.  However, I need to go one more step, extracting the unique values of field 3, e.g,  

    "GB"
    "DE"
  
I've tried several variations without success. May I trouble you for what is probably the obvious modification?  Thank you much.

Comment: Thank you for the follow up.  Happy to report that these options work significantly faster than what I had before.